# updating values in one table if depending table row is affected

Tags: mysql

there are two tables

structure is like:

```
product_table

item_id product_id count_subscriber
1          2           4
2          3           5

subscriber_table

item_id subscriber_id product_id
1         115           2
2         145           2
3         84            3
```

what i want to achieve is if i add/delete one item_id from `subcriber_table` this should update the value in `count_subscriber` (increment/decrement) of `product_table` where `product_id` matches.

is this possible to do this in one query? how should i achieve this in one query? right now what i am doing is first deleting the item_id in `subscriber_table` and than updating the `count_subscriber` in `product_table` and same for addition.

please advise.
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fit in your situation, but a mysql VIEW should work for you, and make things easier.

You could create a VIEW called `product_table`, based on a select over `subscriber_table`, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW product_table AS SELECT item_id, product_id, COUNT(*) AS
count_subscriber  FROM subscriber_table GROUP BY item_id, product_id
```

Using this, you will not need to update manually product_table data on every change made over `subscriber_table`.

Comment: thanks i was not really looking for a View based solution but i should look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **trigger** :

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_subscriber AFTER INSERT ON subscriber_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE product_table SET count_subscriber = count_subscriber + 1 WHERE item_id = NEW.item_id AND product_id = NEW.product_id ;
END
```

Now when you make an **INSERT** in subscriber_table:

```
insert into subscriber_table values (1, 1, 1);
insert into subscriber_table values (1, 2, 1);
insert into subscriber_table values (1, 4, 1);
```

It'll increment the column count_subscriber in product_table:

```
mysql> select * from product_table;
+---------+------------+------------------+
| item_id | product_id | count_subscriber |
+---------+------------+------------------+
|       1 |          1 |                3 |
+---------+------------+------------------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Best Regards

Max.

Comment: i am gonn try that. thanks for your input.